# Как в wordpress в ссылку страницы вставить знаки ? и =

Tags: wordpress

есть сайт и надо сохранить прежние ссылки, а они сделаны на чистом php, задача в переходе на wordpress и когда при создании новой страницы я пытаюсь написать адсесс например site.ru/page?=333, то знаки вопрос и равно исчезают. Как это пофиксить. Я так понял это всё делает htaccess делает. Спасибо
Попробовал прямо в БД прописать вопрос и равно и вот что получилось

```
http://wordpress.test/wp-admin/post.php?post=6&action=edit
```

---

Короч никогда так не делайте, я подправил урлы, добавил рубрику с ?id= и вот что у меня вышло. Плохая идея!
[image: Ахнутнг]

Comment: Выбирай что нужнее - или ВП (и редиректы) или такие кривые ссылки.

Comment: Надо сохранить старые ссылки для старых страниц и потом новые человеческие ссылки что бы были. А что это проблема wp и никак не настроить?

Comment: Ни на ВП ни в любом другом движке не настроить такой зоопарк. Теоретически можно накидав косттылей сделать что ты хочешь, но это чревато для будущей жизни сайта. Правильный подход - сделать редиректы.

Comment: так а в чём сложность получить такую ссылку? site.ru/page?=333 по сути простой гет запрос, а остальные уже делать по нормальным запросам. Может я чего не понимаю, ткните где посмотреть на эту тему.

Comment: кури "роутинг".